# How to compute the correct residue without change of modulus?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Suppose $F=1857$,   $G=2017$, and we want to compute $ FG \equiv 1606$ mod $(2^{11} -1)$.

Also let $t =2^4$, then $F = 1+4t+7t^2$ and $G = 1+14t+7t^2$, where the most significant digits are bounded by $2^3$ i.e. $[0,7]$. Now

$$FG \mod (t^3−1) = (49t^4 + 126t^3 + 70t^2 + 18t + 1) \mod (t^3−1) \\ 
= 70t^2 + 67t + 127$$

To me this reduction is a problem because we are reducing $2^{12} -1$. So what should be done here?

We can compute the correct residue by changing modulus i.e. $2(2^{11} - 1)$ but I don't want it that way.

The other details are given below

Since we know that we have to compute FG mod $2^{11}−1$ and the most significant digits $\in [0,7]$, then we have

$127 \texttt{ mod } 16=15, \qquad 127/16=7, \qquad (67+7) \texttt{ mod } 16=10, \qquad (67+7)/16 = 4, \\ (70+4) \texttt{ mod } 8=2, \qquad (70+4)/8=9, \qquad (15+9) \texttt{ mod } 16=8, \qquad (15+9)/16=1, \\ (10+1) \texttt{ mod } 16=11, \qquad (10+1)/16=0$

Lastly,  FG mod $(2^{11}- 1)=2\cdot 28 + 11\cdot 24 + 8 = 696 \quad$ Wrong

Comment: Why so complicated? Using $2^{11}-1 = 2047$ you get without any computer 
$$1857\times 2017 \equiv (-190)(-30) \equiv 5700  \equiv 5700-4094 \equiv 1606 \pmod{2047}$$

Comment: Because I have simplified the problem and if computing the values in the original problem would have been so easy, then the question does not make any sense.

Comment: $2^{11}-1=2047\neq 1606$.

Comment: Yes, $1606$ is the residue and not the value of $2^{11} - 1$. I will edit the question for more clarity.

Comment: Here $t^3=2^{12}\equiv2\pmod{2^{11}-1}$. Consequently $t^4\equiv2t$. Therefore
$$
(49t^4 + 126t^3 + 70t^2 + 18t + 1)\equiv 2\cdot126+70t^2+(18+2\cdot49)t+1.$$ Don't know if that kind of thinking helps in the general problem you're working on.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Is it not the same as $(49t^4+126t^3+70t^2+18^t+1) \texttt{ mod } t^{3} - 2$? But I don't want to change the modulus i.e. $2^{11} - 1$